# How Delete order and order_mapping table data same time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

How delete two table data in same time

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
   { 
    $order_map = Order_menu_mapping::where('order_id',$id)->get();

    $order = Order::find($id);
    $order->deleted_by = \Auth::user()->email;

    $order->save();
    $order_map->save();

    if ($order->delete()) {
        return ['type' => 'success', 'title' => 'Deleted!', 'message' 
        => 'Order has been deleted successfully.'];
    }
}
```

How delete two table data in same time

Comment: `$order_map` is a collection. There's no `save()` method on a collection. Did you intend `first()` on `Order_menu_mapping`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
DB::table(DB::raw('FROM orders, order_mappings'))
->join(order_mappings) // wasn't clear how your tables were related
->where('order_id', $_POST['id'])
->delete();
```